Create pydantic computed 2.0 computed_field like field on pydatinc 1.10
I am using Pydantic 1.10 and I want to define computed fields in my model so I researched and found this doc about Pydantic 2.0 about computed_field decorator. The problem is that I can't find anything similar for version 1.10 and I'm not allowed to update the version.
How can I achieve in version 1.10 the same I can do in version 2.0?

I found how to do it, this is the way so you don't have to lose any points by posting a question.
You can use the root_validator decorator for the porpoise, just make it return the computed value, like this:
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    field_1: str
    field_2: int
    field_3: int
    product: int

    @root_validator
    def compue_product(cls, values):
        values["product"] = values["field_2"] * values["field_3"]

        return values

Just ensure that the computed field is declared after all other fields required for the computation, or such values wouldn't be available when required.
